# Is non-strippable wallpaper glue favorable to strippable?

Tags: adhesive, wallpaper

I am facing a choice between a strippable vs non-strippable wallpaper glue. Why would not anyone have the option to later strip it for whatever reason if all else is equal? But my question is is everything else equal, or does the non-srippable variant have any advantages that are sacrificed for strippability?

Comment: Think it comes down to your SO changing their minds about wall paper often or let the next people after I am gone worry about it.

Comment: I do a lot of praying every time I have to take down wallpaper that was either 1) put up without sizing or 2) used non-strippable wallpaper.  Am in the middle of doing that now in a vacation condo.  Paper came off OK, but the backing and glue is a different story.

Comment: @SteveH Don't you love it when it peels the face of the drywall off? Just dealt with that on my last job and had to get it back to a level 5.